# How can i handle Android device's framebuffer?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, framebuffer

I want handle Android's frame buffer. I have a rooted Galaxy R(SHV-E170K) for testing, on which I run this command:

```
adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 fb0
```

Then, I run the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb0 -s 540x960 -i fb0 -f image2 -vcodec png frame-%d.png
```

But I get below wrong images.

[image: FFMPEG Images]

How can I correctly handle android's framebuffer?

Thanks.

Comment: looks like the resolution you are using is not right... try to change 540x960 part...

Comment: reaolution is right. I had call ioctl fb info is 540x960...

Comment: Self answer. (I can't write self answer not yet. :( )

i expected to framebuffer size 6220800 bytes (xresv * yresv * bpp/8)
but real framebuffer size is 6266880 bytes (line_length/(bpp/8) * yresv * bpp/8)

xres=540
yres=960 
xresv=540
yresv=2880
bpp=32
line_length : 2176 (...2160 expected)

so i just change xres to 544, this issue cleared

Comment: So it was the resolution after all... ;)